# Render View to string using resources

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, model-view-controller, render, culture

I have resources (resx) files and view that I need to render for sending mail. I use this solution:

```
 protected string RenderPartialViewToString(string viewName, object model)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(viewName))
            viewName = ControllerContext.RouteData.GetRequiredString("action");

        ViewData.Model = model;

        using (StringWriter sw = new StringWriter())
        {
            ViewEngineResult viewResult = ViewEngines.Engines.FindPartialView(ControllerContext, viewName);
            ViewContext viewContext = new ViewContext(ControllerContext, viewResult.View, ViewData, TempData, sw);

            viewResult.View.Render(viewContext, sw);

            return sw.GetStringBuilder().ToString();
        }
    }
```

My view is based on resources that are taken from the user's culture, how do I render the view to support culture?

Answer (score 1):

basically you could do it like this or encapsulate it in your own helper methods.

```
    @Html.ViewContext.HttpContext.GetGlobalResourceObject("resource", key, new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("de-AT")
```

Comment: by the way: you could also create folder structure with the standard MVC convections likes this in your project: Resources/Views. In it you could create a folder named Shared. If you add a Global.resx file there with lets say your general localized strings. Then you can access them like this: @Resources.Global.NameOfResourceKey

Answer (score 1):

I think what you need is to set the CurrentUICulture of the current thread to the culture that you want to use. 
To do that, you need the following code:
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en");//The language name will probably be a parameter
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture;

So your code should look something like:

protected string RenderPartialViewToString(string viewName, object model, string languageName) 
    { 
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(viewName)) 
            viewName = ControllerContext.RouteData.GetRequiredString("action");

```
    ViewData.Model = model; 

    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo(languageName);//The language name will probably be a parameter
    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture;

    using (StringWriter sw = new StringWriter()) 
    { 
        ViewEngineResult viewResult = ViewEngines.Engines.FindPartialView(ControllerContext, viewName); 
        ViewContext viewContext = new ViewContext(ControllerContext, viewResult.View, ViewData, TempData, sw); 

        viewResult.View.Render(viewContext, sw); 

        return sw.GetStringBuilder().ToString(); 
    } 
}
```

And you view will be rendered in the language you need.